# Unable to Post values via RestAssured

Tags: api, post, rest-assured

Am newbee. Developing code using Restassured
Below is my code

```
JSONObject request = new JSONObject(); // created an object
request.put("Name", "this is a");
request.put("ID", "012");
given().
header("Content-Type","application/json").
body(request.toJSONString()).
when().
post("http://localhost:3000/Shop").
then().
statusCode(201).
log().ifError();
My JSON File:
{
    "Shop":[
        {
            "ID":           "001",
            "Name": "ABC"
            
        },
        {
            "ID":           "002",
            "Name": "XYZ"
        }
    ]
}
```

Am getting exception message as
Expected status code <201> but was <500>.

```
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
```

Can any one let me know what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your created json is

```
{
    "ID": "012",
    "Name": "this is a"
}
```

but it requires

```
{
    "Shop":[
        {
            "ID":           "001",
            "Name": "ABC"
            
        },
        {
            "ID":           "002",
            "Name": "XYZ"
        }
    ]
}
```

So you need to change the object of post body. My quick fix for this case is

```
Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<>();
item.put("Name", "this is a");
item.put("ID", "012");

JSONObject shop = new JSONObject();
shop.put("shop", Collections.singleton(item));

given().log().all()
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .body(shop.toJSONString()).
        .when()
        .post("your-url")
        .then()
        .statusCode(201)
        .log().ifError();
```